# state manager for xaml SplitView pane inside frame

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

That's kind of a long title. 
So i have a Shell.xaml with a  for the content .xaml's

```
<Grid>
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="ShellSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="CompactInline"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="ShellSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="Overlay"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<SplitView x:Name="ShellSplitView">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <Grid>
            <ListView x:Name="NavMenuList">
            ...
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame">
    </Frame>
</SplitView>
</Grid>
```

Inside this Frame other .xaml's are loadad for the actual content. Those also use a  (to add further depth, like the mail app: folder->email list->email view) but if i add a  to that nested xaml it doesn't do anything.

My goal would be to have it behave like two separate frames when in small view (like phone), so the user can navigate between them (again, like the win10 mail app).

Right now the VisualStateManager of the Frame xaml looks like this, but this was just a test to see it working. As I mentioned I'd prefer a similar behaviour to the mail app.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="PeopleSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="Inline"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="PeopleSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="CompactInline"/>
                <Setter Target="PeopleSplitView.IsPanelOpen" Value="False"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Also when resizing the Window, the content of the frame splitview content doesn't resize itself and stays full width (thus not wrapping the text).

```
<SplitView x:Name="PeopleSplitView"
           DisplayMode="Inline"
           IsPaneOpen="True"
           OpenPaneLength="400"
           CompactPaneLength="48">

    <SplitView.Pane></SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>
        <Grid Padding="0">
            <ListView.../> 
        </Grid>
    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to delete this element of your c# code that is found in the event of the listview   that selects the frames

i think this should help you

```
private void ListViewSplit_Tapped(object sender,TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
 { 
    //delete those lines
    if (MySplitView.IsPaneOpen)
        MySplitView.IsPaneOpen = !MySplitView.IsPaneOpen;                                           
  }
```